# iPhoneSdk, SQLite database search query not work

Tags: iphone, sqlite

i want to know how to pass particular word or character in search query to find records..
i am passing in the format like '%%%@%%'.
but it doesn't give me output...
this is my code...

```
searchName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"'%%%@%%'",[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"key"]];  
-(void)getSearchData  
{  

        NSLog(@"search Name %@", searchName);   

    searchArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];   

    const char *sql = "select * from features where lower(name) like ? limit 500";  
    if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &selectstmt, NULL)!= SQLITE_OK)  
    {  
        NSAssert1(0,@"error : failed to prepare statement with message '%s'.",sql ite3_errmsg(database));  

      }  
    sqlite3_bind_text(selectstmt, 1, [searchName UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);  
    //  sqlite3_bind_text(selectstmt, 2, [state UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);  

    while (sqlite3_step(selectstmt) == SQLITE_ROW)  
    {   

        NSMutableDictionary *datah = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];  

        [datah setObject:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(selectstmt,0)] forKey:@"number"];  

        [datah setObject:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(selectstmt,1)] forKey:@"name"];  

        [datah setObject:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(selectstmt,2)] forKey:@"type"];  

        [datah setObject:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(selectstmt,4)] forKey:@"country"];  

        [datah setObject:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(selectstmt,5)] forKey:@"lat"];  

        [datah setObject:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(selectstmt,6)] forKey:@"long"];  

        [datah setObject:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(selectstmt,7)] forKey:@"elevation"]; 

        [datah setObject:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(selectstmt,8)] forKey:@"area"];  

        [datah setObject:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(selectstmt,3)] forKey:@"state"];  

        [searchArray addObject:datah];  
        [datah release];  
    }  
    sqlite3_reset(selectstmt);    
}
```

if i pass a same query with word "s" i got 100 of record in sqlite query builder but if m pass through above code it doesn't serach any record
please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I worked on the code given above and fixed it as follows

```
-(void)getSearchData:(NSString*)searchText
{  

    **NSString* searchName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%%%@%%",searchText];**  
    NSLog(@"search Name %@", searchName);   
    sqlite3 *database;
    sqlite3_stmt *selectstmt; 
    NSString* searchQuery = @"SELECT * FROM contacts WHERE lower(name) like ?";
    const char *sql =   [searchQuery UTF8String];
      **if(sqlite3_open([databasePath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) {**
          if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &selectstmt, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)  
          { 
            //NSAssert1(0,@"error : failed to prepare statement with message '%s'.",sql ite3_errmsg(database));  

          }  
          sqlite3_bind_text(selectstmt, 1, [searchName UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_STATIC);  
          while (sqlite3_step(selectstmt) == SQLITE_ROW)  
          {     
            NSLog(@"%@",[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(selectstmt,0)]);
          }  
          sqlite3_reset(selectstmt);    
      }
    sqlite3_close(database);
}
```

The changed portions can be found between Double *. you would also like to read [this](http://www.innerexception.com/2008/10/using-like-statement-in-sqlite-3-from.html)

Two steps that I changed were opening the database connection which You must have done elsewhere and second removing the '' from searchName. Do let us know if this resolves the issue.

Comment: why don't you add your pic? use gravtar.com for you avatar.

Comment: it's really grateful.... i had just made mistake to passing a searchName in query with single quote. thanx once again...

Comment: @Rahul Good job done. +1 for Providing correct code and link to detail description.