# SQLIite Query in .sql file using objective C, iPhone App.

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sql, sqlite

Is it even possible to search data from .sql file containing 20000 entries using objective C in iphone App?

Comment: hope this may help :

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6463229/iphonesdk-sqlite-database-search-query-not-work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [FMDB](https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb), it's a great wrapper around sqlite3 and it will save you a lot of time. You need to get a path to your .sqlite file and instantiate a FMDatabase object.

```
FMDatabase *db = [FMDatabase databaseWithPath:@"path/to/db.sqlite"];
```

Then open it in @try @catch @finally block

```
@try {
  [db open];
  //use this set to fetch data

  FMResultSet *resultSet = [db executeQuery:@"SELECT * FROM table_in_database"];
  while ([resultSet next]) {
    int index = [resultSet intForColumn:@"id"];
    NSString *name = [resultSet stringForColumn:@"name"];

    //etc...
  }
}
@catch (NSException *e) {
}
@finally {
  [db close];
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot bloke, can ya give me an example, because i am not aware of fetching data through sql using objective c, so how to create indexes and stuff would be time consuming, n right now i am kinda on a clock, a simple example would be great!! thnx!